# Can i inject Material UI styles like a link in head (React)?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Right now I see that Material-UI injects the styles in the style tag. And all CSS codes are in the head tag. How can I change this and add the styles like a link?

Comment: Are you asking if it can be used as CDN ??  If that's the case then just use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />`

Comment: Might be helpful `https://cdnjs.com/libraries/material-ui`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but if you use the `className` prop your styles will be injected into the `<head/>` rather than inline.